# How to implement facebook login and registration

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use facebook login and registration on my web page. My webpage is curerntly hosted on localhost and both Facebook login and Register CODE are working properly.
But i cannot figure out how do i use that data to store and write php code.

eg.
Code for registration form

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=&
         redirect_uri=http://localhost:90/store.php&
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

Code for Login button

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Both are displaying and working respectively, but how do i use these variables?

How do i check whether user is already logged in? if not, how do i make him login and redirect to another page with his info. Mainly i dont see any variables in this code to use.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Registration plugins doc: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/
You can find examples there too.